# Angular While enabling html5mode gives Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When I try to remove the `#` character from the URL by enabling the `html5mode` to `true`, it gives the following error for the initial loading:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop
```

When the `html5mode` is `false` everything works fine.

Comment: play around http://ngtutorial.com/learn/route.html#/_tblcontents_5

Comment: The issue comes because of some 3rd party plugins. Now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 3rd party plugins and see if it works, then re-add them until it breaks to find out which one is causing this issue.